# Superset return access to dashbords

Tags: apache-superset, secret-key

I accidentally rewritten my SECRET_KEY key and now I get an error in my dashboards :
Invalid decryption key
Can I somehow return my old key (can be stored somewhere in the database of the superset)?
Or what ways to regain access to my dashboards?

I’ll add that this is not a docker superset